# Is the Class with @Controller annotation a single object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, io

I know that two requests with same content use different threads. And I thought that different threads will create different instances with @Controller annotation. But when I run the code below, I find my thought is wrong.

Test code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestADEDSAController {
    private String string = "";

    @RequestMapping("controllerTest")
    @ResponseBody()
    public String controllerTest(@RequestParam String string) {
        return this.string += string;
    }
}
```

The first time the response content is like:

```
test
```

The second time is like:

```
testtest
```

It seems that there is only one Test instance in the JVM.

I would like to know whether it is true that there is always only one @Controller instance in the JVM? Also, where can I find a detailed introduction about this process?

Comment: `@Controller` does not have property `scope`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Spring creates a single shared instance of the bean. The bean scope is `singleton` by default. In case you need a new instance created on every request, you should define the bean scope as `prototype`. This can either be done by annotating the class with `@Scope("prototype")` or by defining the scope in the spring configuration xml as below:

```
 <bean id="controllerId" class="com.package.name.TestADEDSAController" scope="prototype"/>
```

Please go through https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html to gain better understanding of bean scopes in spring.

Comment: thank you, your answer is very detailed. after i read the doc you give to me, i debug the spring framework source code for research this process, when i debug to Class AbstractUrlHandlerMapping's method lookupHandler(), i find that the field handlerMap's size is six, but i can't find out how it is initialized, it makes me very confused.

Answer (score 4):

By default, all bean in Spring is created as `singleton` (one per IOC container).

This is [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)

> (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default objects are singletons. That mean your objects must be thread safe.
So it's a bad practice to have unsafe values like Strings in your controller (except constants).

You could have your fields corrupted if two threads go there at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Default scope is "singleton", so if you need Spring to create a new instance each time you can use @Scope("prototype") annotation in addition to @Controller annotation. There are also other web-aware scopes like request, session and global session. Read [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) for examples.